# How can I get the response of a click event to handle exception on Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

I am using Selenium to automate some comment actions on a post on Instagram. The flow is the following: the script wait for the textarea to be clickable, then click on it, write the comment and wait for the "Post" button to be clickable and click on it. However, even though I am limiting to very few comments (20 comments/hour) and giving enough time in between, every now and then everything is available for clicking but the comment doesn't go through and a little banner shows on the bottom of the page saying "Couldn't post comment" after clicking on "Post" then the textarea is not clickable anymore.
This is my piece of code:

```py
...
try:
    comment_post = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 10).until(
                   EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")))
    if comment_post.text == "Post":
        comment_post.click()
        sleep(random.randint(2,5))
        return
...
```

The thing is that even when the comment is not posted the `try` statement goes through because the `.click()` action was available. How can I get the response of the click ('couldn't post comment') so that I can raise an exception and put the application to wait until it is availble again or refresh the page or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait and search for the existence of the banner after the click. If you find the banner then raise an exception.

Something like this:

```
comment_post.click()
try:
    nocommentbanner = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 10).until(
               EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.SOMEHOW, someway)))
    # banner found
    # comment fail
    # maybe raise CommentFailed()
except TimeoutException:
    # banner not found
    # comment success
    # perhaps do nothing
```